# Apple script behaves differently on Monterey and Ventura

Tags: macos, applescript

I ran following script on Monterey (12.4) and Ventura (13.2.1) in Terminal :

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "echo hi"
end tell'
```

On Monterey, I get `echo hi`, as expected. But on Ventura, I get `echohi`.

On Ventura :

```
$ osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "echo hi"
end tell'
$ echohi # I type Enter here
-bash: echohi: command not found
```

Comment: Where are you echoing the keystrokes to when you run the script? If I try it on Ventura, and have the cursor positioned after the end of the script, I get `echo hi` as expected. Also I assume you've got Script Editor enabled in Accessibility settings?

Comment: @AndyGriffiths Post updated, just in Terminal. Both messages arrived in Terminal as well.  I have correct Accessibility settings, otherwise, I would get permission errors like messages.

Comment: I'm running Ventura 13.3 (beta) and this is working fine when I run it in my terminal.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that you're running it in `osascript`. I too get the correct output when I do it that way also. Also it works fine in both `zsh` and `bash`. It may be a keyboard language issue?